# How to connect alpinejs code and custom javascript file in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, alpine.js, ruby-on-rails-6.1

This Question might sound stupid. But i am learning alpine while implementing it with rails.

The problem is i am getting this error

```
alpine.js:1914 Uncaught ReferenceError: carouselData is not defined
    at eval (eval at d.el (alpine.js:144:14), <anonymous>:3:36)
    at d.el (alpine.js:144:14)
    at d (alpine.js:131:21)
    at f (alpine.js:139:12)
    at new be (alpine.js:1461:89)
    at Object.initializeComponent (alpine.js:1911:20)
    at alpine.js:1856:14
    at alpine.js:1870:9
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.discoverComponents (alpine.js:1869:15)
```

and my code is

**testimonial_page.html.erb**

```
<div class="mx-auto relative w-full" x-data="carouselData([{id: 1, text: 'first'}])">
  <!-- INNER CODE -->
</div>
```

**app/javascript/packs/testimonial.js**

```
function carouselData(slides) {
  return {
    slides,
    activeSlide: 1,
    goToPrevious() {
      this.activeSlide =
        this.activeSlide === 1 ? this.slides.length : this.activeSlide - 1;
    },
    goToNext() {
      this.activeSlide =
        this.activeSlide === this.slides.length ? 1 : this.activeSlide + 1;
    }
  };
}

console.log("hi testimonial file loaded")
```

I am getting **hi testimonial file loaded** in the console but still getting that error.
I am so confused what's wrong ?

Although it is working fine if i put the script in same page
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How can this code work when `[id: 1, text: 'first']` is not valid JS? Maybe you wanted to pass list of objects: `[{id: 1, text: 'first'}, {id: 2, text: 'second'}]`? How/where do you include the `testimonials.js` script in the page?

Comment: @Dauros Yes i updated the syntax.

Comment: Could you please answer my second question as well? How and where do you embed the `testimonial.js` script into the page? It's an important detail in this case, since you have script-embedding problems.

Comment: @Dauros I embedded the code in testimonial.html.erb itself. And there it is working fine

Comment: Before Alpine.js or after?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't have a key for the `slides` object.

Change the `carouselData` function to

```
function carouselData(slides = null) {
  return {
    slides: slides,
    activeSlide: 1,
    goToPrevious() {
      this.activeSlide =
        this.activeSlide === 1 ? this.slides.length : this.activeSlide - 1;
    },
    goToNext() {
      this.activeSlide =
        this.activeSlide === this.slides.length ? 1 : this.activeSlide + 1;
    }
  };
}
```

Also you might consider assigning the `slides` inside `x-init` just in case, you don't have to though, especially I assume slides are rendered on the server first.

```
<div class="mx-auto relative w-full" 
  x-data="carouselData()"
  x-init="slides = [{id: 1, text: 'first'}]"
>
  <!-- INNER CODE -->
</div>
```

If you take that route, I'd do something like this as well:

```
<template x-if="slides.length">
  <!-- render slides -->
</template>
```